# Returning an element and then deleting the element from a list in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I have a list in Scheme which contains numbers. I wrote a function that takes as input one number and a list of objects and checks if the confidence value of the object matches the number.

Once I get the object whose confidence values matches the given number, I want to delete the object from the list after returning it. How do I do this? This is my code so far:

```
(define (get-wordpair mi wordpairs)
    (define current-wp (car wordpairs))
    (define confidence (tv-conf (cog-tv current-wp)))
    (if (equal? confidence mi)
        current-wp
        (get-wordpair mi (cdr wordpairs))))
```

Comment: Sample input and the expected output would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter` for deleting from the list those objects whose confidence value matches the given number:

```
(filter (lambda (e)
          (not (equal? (tv-conf (cog-tv e)) mi)))
        wordpairs)
```

Conversely, this expression will return a list with those objects that *do* have the expected confidence (it's possible that there's more than one!)

```
(filter (lambda (e)
          (equal? (tv-conf (cog-tv e)) mi))
        wordpairs)
```

So, call *both* expressions to obtain two lists with the required objects, if it's ok to perform two passes over the input list. For a more efficient solution that performs a single pass check your interpreter's documentation to see if it provides a [`partition`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._partition%29%29) procedure, or use [SRFI-1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#FilteringPartitioning):

```
(let-values (((with-confidence no-confidence)
              (partition (lambda (e)
                           (equal? (tv-conf (cog-tv e)) mi))
                         wordpairs)))
  ; do something with the list of objects that have the
  ; required confidence (with-confidence) and the list of
  ; those which don't have the confidence (no-confidence)
  )
```